# How do I reference a class from Javascript as a template in KendoGrid?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid, a javascript GridView.

```
  columns: function () {

    return [

        {
            title: "Icon",
            width: 32,
            template: function (data)
           {

            }

        },
        {
            field: "DisplayFileName",
            title: "Document Name",
            width: 300,
            //template: function (data) {



            //}

         },

        {
            field: "DocumentType",
            title: "DocumentType",
            titleKey: 'Document Type',
            filterable: true,
        },
```

For the Icon Column, I need to reference `'<i class="fa fa-warning red"></i>`' How do I reference it? how do I put in the template so the icon of that class appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing like this in my project (it shows button with icon) :

```
{ 
    title: "&#9733;", 
    width: "50px", 
    template: '<a class="btn btn-primary k-grid-custom-btn search-btn details-small-btn"></a>' 
}
```